# No module named dask even though I could see the library is installed

Tags: python, dask

I am having problem to import dask even though I installed by `conda install dask` and confirmed that there is module in site-packages folder. Does anyone know what is causing this problem? I added the screenshot of the problem.
[image]

Comment: It is work checking `sys.exec_prefix` and `sys.path` to make sure that the kernel running in jupyter is pointing to the locations you think it is.

Comment: Also, try creating a virtualenv and install dask in it.